# Bacula - Fatal error: Authorization key rejected by Storage daemon

Tags: backup, bacula

OS: Debian 9, bacula dir, fd, sd : all same versions 7.4.4+dfsg-6
Trying to perform restore of some files(not full set), getting error on FD:

`4-Nov 12:20 host-dir JobId 273: Start Restore Job RestoreFiles.2017-11-24_12.20.32_48
24-Nov 12:20 host-dir JobId 273: Using Device "FileChgr1-Dev1" to read.
24-Nov 12:20 host-remote-fd JobId 273: Fatal error: Authorization key rejected by Storage daemon.
For help, please see http://www.bacula.org/rel-manual/en/problems/Bacula_Frequently_Asked_Que.html
24-Nov 12:20 host-dir JobId 273: Fatal error: Bad response to Storage command: wanted 2000 OK storage
, got 2902 Bad storage`

Error on Director:

`24-Nov 12:20 host-dir JobId 273: Error: Bacula host-dir 7.4.4 (202Sep16):
  Build OS:               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu debian 9.0
  JobId:                  273
  Job:                    RestoreFiles.2017-11-24_12.20.32_48
  Restore Client:         host-remote-fd
  Start time:             24-Nov-2017 12:20:34
  End time:               24-Nov-2017 12:20:46
  Files Expected:         3
  Files Restored:         0
  Bytes Restored:         0
  Rate:                   0.0 KB/s
  FD Errors:              2
  FD termination status:

  SD termination status:  Waiting on FD
  Termination:            *** Restore Error ***`

Error on SD:

`host-remote-sd: bnet.c:566-0 who=client host=127.0.0.1 port=9103
host-remote-sd: hello.c:134-0 Conn: Hello Bacula SD: Start Job RestoreFiles.2017-11-24_12.20.32_48 213
host-remote-sd: hello.c:147-0 Client connect failed: Job name not found: RestoreFiles.2017-11-24_12.20.32_48
host-remote-sd: hello.c:148-0 **** Job "RestoreFiles.2017-11-24_12.20.32_48" not found.`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Resolution is simple. In director defined 2 SD, local as localhost(127.0.0.1 on Director host), and remote with IP. When I tried to restore to remote FD from local storage, remote FD tried to connect localhost, and the key was wrong. Director send task to FD with SD IP as configured.
Changing local SD configuration(on same host as Director) with public IP instead of localhost, allowed remote-FD connect to proper host to get the files for restore.